# Two UISlider and UILabel setting them programmatically but does not know which slider is slides

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I have an iOS project in which I am setting up two sliders and corresponding labels.
Labels are for the slider value. When they slide, the value in the labels change.

I have another class in which I set the slider and label after they create and save that instance in the array. The difficulty I face is when I slide the slider, I do not know which slider is slides.

Here is code:

SliderWidget Class

```
class SliderWidget {

    private var label: UILabel?
    private var slider: UISlider?

    public func setLable(label: UILabel) {
        self.label = label
    }

    public func setSlider(slider: UISlider) {
        self.slider = slider
    }

    public func getLabel() -> UILabel {
        return self.label!
    }

    public func getSlider() -> UISlider {
        return slider!
    }
}
```

Here is the controller on which I set slider and label

```
class WidgetsVC: UIViewController {

    private let step: Float = 10
    private var labels: UILabel?
    private var sliderArray: Array<SliderWidget> = Array()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        displaySlider(sliderY: 100,labelY: 70)
        displaySlider(sliderY: 200, labelY: 170)
    }

    private func displaySlider(sliderY: Int, labelY: Int) {

        let slider = UISlider()
        slider.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2980392277, green: 0.6862744689, blue: 0.3137254715, alpha: 1)

        let label = displayLabel(labelY: labelY, slider: slider)
        view.addSubview(slider)

        let horizonalContraints =
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: slider, attribute: .leadingMargin,
                               relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view,
                               attribute: .leadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0,
                               constant: 20)

        let horizonal2Contraints =
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: slider, attribute: .trailingMargin,
                               relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view,
                               attribute: .trailingMargin, multiplier: 1.0,
                               constant: -20)

        let pinTop =
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: slider, attribute: .top,
                               relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view,
                               attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0,
                               constant: CGFloat(sliderY))

        slider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizonalContraints, horizonal2Contraints, pinTop])

        slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(WidgetsVC.sliderValueDidChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    }

    private func displayLabel(labelY: Int, slider: UISlider) -> UILabel {

        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "0"
        labels = label
        view.addSubview(label)

        let temp = SliderWidget()
        temp.setLable(label: label)
        temp.setSlider(slider: slider)
        sliderArray.append(temp)

        let horizonalContraints =
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .leadingMargin,
                               relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view,
                               attribute: .leadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0,
                               constant: 20)

        let pinTop =
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .top,
                               relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view,
                               attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0,
                               constant: CGFloat(labelY))

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizonalContraints, pinTop])

        return label
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you keep a reference to each of the sliders you create? You can set the tag of each slider to be a unique integer and compare them later to figure out which is which. slider.tag = 0, slider.tag = 1...

Comment: Do you need to create everything programmatically? It would be quite a bit simpler to use Interface Builder to design your "SliderWidget" as a custom view, and then load / display / manage as many as you want at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you want for exactly but you could do it in this way

```
@objc func sliderValueDidChange(slider: UISlider) {
    print(slider.tag)
    let changedSliderWidget = sliderArray.filter { (sliderWidget) -> Bool in
      return sliderWidget.getSlider() == slider
    }.last
  }
```

`changedSliderWidget` will contain the widget that you need

Answer (score -1):

The easy way to identify each one is to set tag values:

```
displaySlider(sliderY: 100,labelY: 70, tag: 1)
displaySlider(sliderY: 200, labelY: 170, tag: 2)
```

And

```
private func displayLabel(labelY:Int,slider:UISlider, tag: Int)->UILabel{
    let label=UILabel()
    label.tag = tag
    label.text="0"
    ....
```

So you can identify the sliders with their .tag value.